# How can I simulate counts data (i.e., compositional data) in Python similar to sklearn.datasets.make_classifications?

Tags: scikit-learn, dataset

I'm trying to test out some methods on compositional data and would like to use some synthetic data.  I found `sklearn`'s `make_classification` class but realized the output of this is normally distributed negative and positive continuous.  What I'm looking for is counts data so positive integers (including 0).

Ideally, I'd like to have similar parameters as `sklearn`'s `make_classification` but the most important would be:

1. Number of classes;
2. Number of features;
3. Number of informative features;
4. Number of redundant features;

and two addition parameters:

5. Total number of counts in sample;
6. Sparsity (% of data that is 0).

My first thought would be to start with NumPy's `randint` object to produce random integers but that's not necessarily what I want because I want there to be some meaning in the features.

**How can I generate synthetic counts data that has some structure?**

Is there anyway I can transform the output of `make_classifications` to fit these specs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this function we could get close to what you expect:

```py
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
import numpy as np

def generate_synthetic_count_data(n_samples, n_features, n_informative, n_redundant, n_classes, total_counts, sparsity, random_state=None):
    # Generate normally distributed data
    X, y = make_classification(n_samples=n_samples, n_features=n_features, n_informative=n_informative, n_redundant=n_redundant, 
                               n_classes=n_classes, random_state=random_state)

    # Scale the data to positive range
    X = X - np.min(X)
    X = X / np.max(X)

    # Scale to the total count
    X = X * total_counts

    # Round to get integer count data
    X = np.round(X).astype(int)

    # Add Poisson noise to introduce variability and simulate real-world count data
    X = np.random.poisson(lam=X)

    # Adjust for sparsity by setting values below a certain threshold to 0
    threshold = np.percentile(X, sparsity*100)
    X[X < threshold] = 0

    return X, y
```

Use it like this:

```
X, y = generate_synthetic_count_data(n_samples=1000,
                                     n_features=20,
                                     n_informative=2,
                                     n_redundant=10, n_classes=2,
                                     total_counts=1000,
                                     sparsity=0.1,
                                     random_state=42)
```

Comment: This answers the question I asked.  I should have been more specific about using a negative binomial distribution but I realize that I didn't ask that initially.  Also, removing the lower values could make a bias.  I'm not sure that the original clusters will be preserved with this implementation.  I'll ask another more detail one later but thank you.